# Working with Golang and a Windows Server Machine

Tags: go, server

I am fairly new and interested in the Go programming language. I have the intention of using it to code a simple website that includes a shopping cart.

- How to install golang on windows server? Is it the same process as a regular computer?
- What steps do I take to deploy the website using the Windows server once it is finished.
- To what extend is it required to use html, css, or javascript?
- How can I keep the site running on the server for other users in our network/LAN to access it?

Any helpful information regarding web apps and/or windows server machines is appreciated!

Comment: This is likely to be closed for being too broad, but a few tips: go executables require nothing to be installed on the server itself. You can just drop an executable from your dev machine or build server and it will run.

Comment: I have installed go apps as windows services using nssm, or the native service manager apis, but that can be tricky.

Comment: I like to deploy go apps with html/css/js actually compiled into the main binary (true single file deploys). Using tools like https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata. My app will serve them as part of it's normal routes.

Answer (score 5):

This is as much a general dev ops question as it is specific to Go. A lot of things to consider here and everyone will have varying preferences but here are some guidelines I'd recommend:

- It's not necessary to install the Go tool chain on your production server. You then have to maintain your Go installation on both your development and production environments and if your production server is a different OS than your Windows computer (eg. a Linux distribution) this will get out of hand quickly. Instead, just develop on your local and [cross compile](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5) to the OS of your production server.
- One thing you will need to keep on your production server is whatever DB you choose to work with your Go program.
- You can then `sftp` or transfer through a method of your choice your compiled binary over to your production server along with your static web files. Once the binary is on your production server you can fire it up when you're SSH'ed in eg. `./programname`
- Depending on how you want to use Go, you don't need Apache. Use the [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package to serve up your Html, CSS and JS files. You can transfer these static files over after you've worked on them on your local or you can just keep them in a Github repo and `git pull` them from your prod server as needed, assuming you've installed git there.
- You generally don't need to worry about keeping it "running" on your production server. [`http.ListenAndServe`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.ListenAndServe) listens on your port for incoming requests. If your server reboots or shuts downs you can automatically have your compiled binary start up along with it.

You can also work with things like Vagrant, Virtual Box and Ansible for high quality mimicking of your production environment and spinning up new servers according to your desired specs.